# If different radio buttons are clicked, only the value of the last one will be saved

Tags: java, android, radio-button, radio-group

his is the part 2 of a quiz application that I created. The first part works fine, but on this part, when I click a radio button, the score will just stack up. For example, if I click Radio Button 2, and then click Radio Button 3, the score will become 3 instead of just 2.

If I try to move the getAnswer() to the OnClickListener in the button, If I click a radio button it won't proceed to the next activity unless I click a different radio button.

```
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.activity_part2);


   firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
   firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();

   gadChoice1 = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.part2Choice1);
   gadChoice2 = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.part2Choice2);
   gadChoice3 = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.part2Choice3);
   gadChoice4 = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.part2Choice4);
   btnNext = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnNext);

   getAnswer();

   DatabaseReference myRef = firebaseDatabase.getReference(firebaseAuth.getUid()).child("test");
   myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
       @Override
       public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
           UserHistory userHistory = dataSnapshot.getValue(UserHistory.class);
           anxHistory = userHistory.getAnx();
           depHistory = userHistory.getDep();

       }

       @Override
       public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
           Toast.makeText(Part2.this, databaseError.getCode(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       }
   });

   btnNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {


                   anxValue = anxHistory + anx;

                   final DatabaseReference myRef = firebaseDatabase.getReference(firebaseAuth.getUid()).child("test");

                   myRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                       @Override
                       public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                           HashMap<String, Object> result = new HashMap<>();
                           result.put("anx", anxValue);
                           myRef.updateChildren(result);
                       }

                       @Override
                       public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                           System.out.println("The read failed: " + databaseError.getMessage());
                       }
                   });

           if(dep > anx){
               Intent myIntent = new Intent(Part2.this, Part3.class);
               startActivity(myIntent);
               finish();
           }else if (anx > dep){
               Intent myIntent = new Intent(Part2.this, Part3.class);
               startActivity(myIntent);
               finish();
           }
       }
   });   }

   private void getAnswer() {
   radioGroup2 = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroup2);
   radioGroup2.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

       @Override
       public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
           if (checkedId == R.id.part2Choice2) {
               anx++ ;
           } else if (checkedId == R.id.part2Choice3)  {
               anx = anx + 2 ;
           }
           else if (checkedId == R.id.part2Choice4) {
               anx = anx + 3;
           }


       }
   });

   }
```

I expect the output to be the value of the radio button selected and not the sum of the radio button that I have clicked. For example, if I clicked Radio button A (0), Radio Button B (1), Radio Button C(2), the output that I will record is 2.

Comment: what if `part2Choice1` is clicked? You have no condition to check it

Comment: The value of part2Choice1 is 0 so I didn't include it there. @VivekMishra

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't handle it inside the the `onCheckedChanged` because it will increments every time you change the selected one. You can test on the selected one when clicking `btnNext` :

```
int selectedItem = radioGroup2.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
if (selectedItem == R.id.part2Choice2) {
    anx++ ;
} else if (checkedId == R.id.part2Choice3)  {
    anx = anx + 2 ;
}
else if (checkedId == R.id.part2Choice4) {
    anx = anx + 3;
}
```